# Java Native Interface For Accessing Photoshop Library

Tags: java

I need to access photoshop library.But photoshop doesn't provide library for java . But C# have this library i need to access this library from C# code into Java using JNI.Is this possible? If possible then How is it ?

Comment: IKVM could be the key for that

Answer (score 0):

That's **Possible**.

As we know, .NET Dymanic Library are all based on DLL (Dymanic Link Library).

And JNI **could load DLLs**, so you can load .NET Library **as normal C/C++ dll**.

But you should make a "hub dll" ***before*** loading Photoshop DLL, as it can **transform .NET structure and normal C/C++ structure**, and put all **Photoshop Functions** in it.

So it's **hard**. And I **recommend** you use **Open-Source Picture Editor/Library**.